# How can make threading for class in python

Tags: python

I need to make threading for this class. This class has to thing one is for GUI and another for socket server. I need to start them at the same time.

```
class msyslog(Frame):
def __init__(self, title, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)  # initialize base class
    self.pack()
    self.master.title(title)

    self.var_ip =StringVar()
    self.var_port =IntVar()
    self.var_db =StringVar()
    self.var_user =StringVar()
    self.var_pas =StringVar()

    Label(self, text="ip address: ").pack(side=LEFT)
    Entry(self, textvariable=self.var_ip).pack(side=LEFT)
    Label(self, text="port number: ").pack(side=LEFT)
    Entry(self, textvariable=self.var_port).pack(side=LEFT)
    Label(self, text="database: ").pack(side=LEFT)
    Entry(self, textvariable=self.var_db).pack(side=LEFT)
    Label(self, text="database user: ").pack(side=LEFT)
    Entry(self, textvariable=self.var_user).pack(side=LEFT)
    Label(self, text="database password: ").pack(side=LEFT)
    Entry(self, textvariable=self.var_pas).pack(side=LEFT)

    Button(self, width=15, text="ENTER", command=self.enter).pack(side=LEFT)
    #Frame.destroy(self)

def enter(self):
    port=self.var_port.get()
    ip=self.var_ip.get()

    HOST, PORT =ip,port

    global table_name
    global db_name
    global db_host
    global db_user
    global db_password
    '''
    db_name = "n9WI5VQpzX"
    table_name = 'logs'
    db_user = 'n9WI5VQpzX'
    db_password = 'Tcp7ydFTZw'
    db_host = 'remotemysql.com'
    db_port = 3306
    '''
    db_name = self.var_db.get()
    table_name = 'logs'
    db_user = self.var_user.get()
    db_password = self.var_pas.get()
    db_host = 'remotemysql.com'
    db_port = 3306


    try:
        # mysql_connection=mysql.connector.connect(user =db_user, password =db_password, host = db_host, port = db_port)
        mysql_connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_password)
    except:
        print('Error:')

    cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
    create_db(db_name, cursor)

    cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
    create_table(db_name, table_name, cursor)

    mysql_connection.commit()

    mysql_connection.close()


    server = socketserver.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), SyslogUDPHandler)
    server.db_name = db_name
    server.table_name = table_name
    server.db_user = db_user
    server.db_password = db_password
    server.db_host = db_host
    server.db_port = db_port

    server.serve_forever()
```

I need to make threading for this class. this class has to thing one is for GUI and another for socket server. I need to start them at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the threading module in order to create 2 threads, one for each function you wanna use, example:

```py
 import threading
 def __init__(self):
    self.a = Thread(target = self.func1,args=(argument1,)) 
    self.b = Thread(target = self.func2,args=(argument2,))
    activate_threads(self)


 def func1(self,argument1):
    pass
 def func2(self,argument2):
    pass
 def activate_threads(self):
    a.start()
    b.start()
```

so you simply need to assign a thread for each function, and decide when to start it.
Id recommend reading more about the threading module, you can use [this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)